# Multiple views layouting in NSScrollView using Visual AutoLayout

Tags: objective-c, macos, autolayout, nsview, nsscrollview

I need to show multiple views aligned vertically inside `NSScrollView`, I started by adding `NSTableView` and `NSButton`. I aligned them vertically with `NSTableView` on top and `NSButton` on bottom.
 I added `NSTableview` and `NSButton` to an `NSView` called *tempView*. And then set the document view of `NSScrollView` to *tempView*.

But problem i am having is my tableview does not expand properly i see the buttons alright but tablview does not expands properly and just show the last entries that fits in the table. 
As you can see in following image it displays last 4 rows of 20 rows.
[image]]
My code is as follow

```
-(void)setupView {
    _scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] init];
    [_scrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
    [_scrollView setHasVerticalRuler:YES];
    [_scrollView setBorderType:NSBezelBorder];
    [_scrollView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor purpleColor]];
         _scrollView.autoresizingMask = NSViewHeightSizable;

    _tableView = [[NSTableView alloc] init];
    [_tableView setDataSource:self];
    [_tableView setHeaderView:nil];
    [_tableView addTableColumn:[[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"firstColumn"]];
    [_tableView setDelegate:self];
    [_tableView setColumnAutoresizingStyle:NSTableViewUniformColumnAutoresizingStyle];
    [_tableView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor greenColor]];

    NSButton* _button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    NSView* tempView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];

    [tempView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_scrollView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_tableView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [tempView addSubview:_button];
    [tempView addSubview:_tableView];

    [_scrollView setDocumentView:tempView];
    [self addSubview:_scrollView];


    NSString *const kViewContainerVertical = @"V:|[tempView]|";
    NSString *const kViewContainerHorizontal = @"H:|[tempView]|";

    NSDictionary *viewDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(tempView);

    NSArray *contraintOneView = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:kViewContainerVertical
                                                                        options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:viewDictionary];

    NSArray *constraintTwoView = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:kViewContainerHorizontal
                                                                         options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:viewDictionary];


    NSString *const kViewVertical = @"V:|[_tableView]-2-[_button]|";
    NSString *const kTextViewHorizontal = @"H:|[_tableView(_button)]-0-|";
    NSString *const kButtonHorizontal = @"H:|-0-[_button]-0-|";

    NSDictionary *dictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_tableView, _button);

    NSArray *contraintOne = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:kViewVertical
                                                                    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                      views:dictionary];

    NSArray *constraintTwo = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:kTextViewHorizontal
                                                                     options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:dictionary];

    NSArray *constraintThree = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:kButtonHorizontal
                                                                       options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:dictionary];
    [tempView addConstraints:contraintOne];
    [tempView addConstraints:constraintTwo];
    [tempView addConstraints:constraintThree];

    [_scrollView.contentView addConstraints:contraintOneView];
    [_scrollView.contentView addConstraints:constraintTwoView];


    NSString *const kScrollVertical = @"V:|-0-[_scrollView]-0-|";
    NSString *const kScrollHorizontal = @"H:|-0-[_scrollView]-0-|";

        NSDictionary *scrollDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_scrollView);

    NSArray *contraintOneScroll = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:kScrollVertical
                                                                    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                      views:scrollDictionary];

    NSArray *constraintTwoScroll = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:kScrollHorizontal
                                                                     options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:scrollDictionary];

    [self addConstraints:contraintOneScroll];
    [self addConstraints:constraintTwoScroll];
}
```

I am not getting the reason for such behavior.

```
[_tableView constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical]
```

Returns

```
<__NSArrayI 0x608000101050>(
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x6080000a2520 V:[NSButton:0x608000140c60'Button'(21)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082620 V:[NSButton:0x608000140c60'Button']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x608000121180 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080000825d0 V:[NSTableView:0x1004032f0]-(2)-[NSButton:0x608000140c60'Button']>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082da0 V:|-(0)-[JSFlippedView:0x608000160cc0]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x610000120140 )>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000081770 h=-&- v=-&- V:|-(1)-[NSClipView:0x100408c20]   (Names: '|':NSScrollView:0x6080001c0000 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082490 V:[NSView:0x608000121180]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSClipView:0x100408c20 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080000828a0 V:[NSScrollView:0x6080001c0000]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':JSFlippedView:0x608000160cc0 )>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000082fd0 h=-&- v=-&- V:[NSView:0x610000120140]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSThemeFrame:0x100403e30'ScrollTest-expand' )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082df0 V:[JSFlippedView:0x608000160cc0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x610000120140 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082440 V:|-(0)-[NSView:0x608000121180]   (Names: '|':NSClipView:0x100408c20 )>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000081540 h=-&- v=-&- V:[NSClipView:0x100408c20]-(1)-|   (Names: '|':NSScrollView:0x6080001c0000 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082850 V:|-(0)-[NSScrollView:0x6080001c0000]   (Names: '|':JSFlippedView:0x608000160cc0 )>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000083200 h=-&- v=-&- V:|-(22)-[NSView:0x610000120140]   (Names: '|':NSThemeFrame:0x100403e30'ScrollTest-expand' )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082580 V:|-(0)-[NSTableView:0x1004032f0]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x608000121180 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000806e0 'NSWindow-current-height' V:[NSThemeFrame:0x100403e30'ScrollTest-expand'(727@500)] priority:500>
)
```

and `_tableView intrinsicContentSize` gives `{-1, -1}`.

Comment: What happens if you do `[_tableView setContentCompressionResistancePriority:750 forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical]`? I suspect the window will grow to show the entire table (perhaps taller than your screen). If so, I can suggest a solution. By the way, you seem to be passing `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft` for all of your constraint-creation calls. This doesn't seem necessary or appropriate. I don't think it has anything to do with the problem, but change it to 0.

Comment: @KenThomases `[_tableView setContentCompressionResistancePriority:750 forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical]` did not change anything.

Comment: OK. At some point after the table has content and has been laid out, log its `intrinsicContentSize` and `[_tableView constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical]`.

Comment: @KenThomases  intrinsicContentSize gives {-1, -1} and for `[_tableView constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical]` i have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the table view has no intrinsic height. Therefore, it's not "pushing" against the document view's bounds to make the document view larger, so it scrolls.

I notice that if I add a table view to a window in IB and then tell IB to reset the whole window (or the clip view or table view) to suggested constraints, there are no constraints added between the table view and the clip view. Also, the table view still has `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` enabled. This is different from some other types of views in scroll views. So, I think that IB knows that table views aren't auto layout-savvy.

I believe that a table view directly in a clip view (as IB sets one up) just uses the old style mechanism for positioning and sizing itself. When a table view computes its size (e.g. a row is added), it probably just calls `-setFrameSize:` on itself. The clip view monitors its frame by observing `NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification` notification. This doesn't work in your case because auto layout basically ignores/undoes attempts to set the frame.

You *may* be able to work with this, but it will be dicey. You would leave the table view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on, but that imposes limits on what constraints you can set without causing conflicts. Basically, you can't set constraints that impose a position or size on the table view, but you can "hang" other views off of the table view so long as they are free to move or resize so that the table view is free to move and resize.

First, your document view (`tempView`) should be a flipped view, because you're going to want to position the table view at its top by setting its frame and then it's going to resize itself by setting its frame size and you want it to grow down.

Init the document view with a frame with non-zero size. The origin doesn't matter.

Init the table view with a frame whose origin is at (0, 0) and with the same size as the document view. Don't forget to leave its `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on.

Do not constrain the top, leading, or trailing edges of the table view to its superview. Don't constrain its width to match the button. The other constraints between the table view and its superview and button are fine, I think. So, `kViewVertical` should drop the first `|`. You should get rid of `kTextViewHorizontal` entirely. `kButtonHorizontal` is fine.

Set the table view's `autoresizingMask` to `NSViewWidthSizable`. Since the table view started with a frame coincident with its superview's bounds, that will keep the table view's left and right edges matching the superview's. There is no vertical component of the `autoresizingMask`. Basically, you don't want changes in the height of the superview to try to change the height of the table view. The table view is free to set its own frame height. That will move the button, because it's constrained to the table view's bottom, and that will change the height of the document view, because its bottom is constrained to the button's bottom.

Do not constrain the document view (`tempView`) to the clip view on its bottom edge. That just tries to force the document view to be the size of the `contentSize` of the scroll view. That is sure to prevent scrolling (by making the scroll view and the window grow to show the entire document view). Rather, the document view will change size as discussed in the previous paragraph and the clip view will notice that and update the scroll view accordingly.

I think that at this point, things will mostly work. I suspect that when the scroll view is large enough to show both the button and the whole table view, they will be pinned to the bottom of the scroll view rather than the top which would be more natural. To fix that, use a subclass of `NSClipView` that is flipped.

Comment: That solved it for me, things i come to know about tableview that i did not know before thanks for the answer, You made my weekend.

Comment: Its interesting that we anchored the top of tableview what if we want to show two table views and what them to layout vertically?

Comment: Tried it by adding table to another view and adding that new view to old table and it worked as well :)