# Objective C Visual Autolayout NSTextField dynamic height

Tags: objective-c, macos, autolayout, visual-format-language

I am trying to create a dynamic size `NSView` using visual auto layout. I am trying to achieve something like the following diagram.

[image]

I added following constraints to achieve this.

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-15-[_iconImageView(39)]-12-[_textView(239)]-15-|"
                                                             options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop metrics:nil views:views]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-15-[_textView]-4-[_mainButton]-5-|"
                                                             options: NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft metrics:nil views:views]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[_mainButton]-15-[_secondaryButton]"
                                                             options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop metrics:nil views:views]];
```

But this creates the following layout.

[image]

As per my understanding, the following VFL will layout _textView 15px from top and then layout _mainButton after 4px from _textView bottom. But in actual _mainbottom is layout after 4px from top of _textView. Am i missing something here?

> @"V:|-15-[_textView]-4-[_mainButton]-5-|"

## Update

---

I replaced `NSTextView` with `NSTextField`. But now the problem is, NSTextField does not grow more than a single line height, but `NSTextField` is multi-line. Complete code for layouting and setting up views is as follow.

```
-(void)setupView {
    _textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    [[_textField cell] setWraps:YES];
    [_textField setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [[_textField cell] setTitle:@"This is a _textView, This will contain dynamic resizing text."];

    [_textField setSelectable:NO];
    [_textField setEditable:NO];
    [_textField setDelegate:self];
    [_textField setBordered:NO];
    [_textField sizeToFit];
    [_textField setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self addSubview:_textField];
    
    _iconImageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    [_iconImageView setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"notify-warning-icon"]];
    [_iconImageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self addSubview:_iconImageView];
    
    _mainButton = [[NSButton alloc] init];
    _mainButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [_mainButton setTitle:@"_mainButton"];
    [self addSubview:_mainButton];
    
    _secondaryButton = [[NSButton alloc] init];
    _secondaryButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [_secondaryButton setTitle:@"_secondaryButton"];
    [self addSubview:_secondaryButton];
    
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_textField,_iconImageView,_mainButton,_secondaryButton);
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-15-[_iconImageView(39)]-12-[_textField(239)]-15-|"
                                                                 options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-15-[_textField]-4-[_mainButton]-5-|"
                                                                 options: NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[_mainButton]-15-[_secondaryButton]"
                                                                 options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop metrics:nil views:views]];
    
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.f constant:320.f]];
}
```

[image]

But if it changed this

```
@"V:|-15-[_textField]-4-[_mainButton]-5-|"
```

with this

```
@"V:|-15-[_textField(>=40)]-4-[_mainButton]-5-|"
```

I get the following output

[image]

But the problem is textfield content is dynamic and could change at runtime, it could be 2 lines, 3 lines etc. So how could i add some height constraint to `NSTextField` that will change `NSTextField` height depending on its content.

Comment: Since you posted diagrams and not real screenshots, it's hard to tell: does the text view really draw? I suspect it's getting 0 height due to lack of sufficient constraints to give it any other height. Also, is there a reason you're using a text view rather than a text **field**, with its built-in support for computing a height based on its content and `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`? For that matter, your window looks just like an `NSAlert`. Could you use one of those instead of reinventing it?

Comment: This is not a diagram Second is a screenshot. Actually i can definitely use a NSTextField, And text view does draw. Actually this will not be a window it will be a part of some view so i can not use NSAlert

Comment: @KenThomases I replaced `NSTextView` with `NSTextField` and posted the updated question.

Comment: Did you set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` on the text field? I'm not seeing that in the code. That is necessary for the text field to compute an intrinsic content size with a height big enough to hold the wrapped text.

Comment: Oh that solved it for me `_textField(239)` I thought defining 239 here would be enough. Thanks @KenThomases you can post the answer here for others and i will mark it as answer.

Comment: @KenThomases There is another layout question i have posted if you could kindly have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524577/multiple-views-layouting-in-nsscrollview-using-visual-autolayout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a text field rather than a text view and set its `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property.

By default, if `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` is 0, a text field will compute its intrinsic size as though its content were laid out in one long line (or, at least, without any maximum width). Even if you apply a constraint that limits its actual width, that doesn't change its intrinsic height and therefore it typically won't be tall enough to contain the text as wrapped.

If you set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, then the text field will compute its intrinsic size based on the text as wrapped to that width. That includes making its intrinsic height tall enough to fit.