# NSTableView inside NSOutlineView and NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I'm building a OS X application using Swift and Xcode 6.4 on OS X 10.10.5.
On a specific view of my application I would like to have a view like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrKL8.png) one Xcode has on the Data Model Editor.

I tried to replicate this view using an OutlineView where each "row" would have a title and a TableView plus two buttons (for the plus and minus buttons). For tests purposes I've separated the title for the TableView+Buttons, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zREz.png) (this was one of many different attempts).

Everything is working as expected except the View that has the TableView+Buttons, that is never higher than 17 pixels. If I define everything in one view, I have the same problem. I've tried defining the needed constraints but in that case there is a problem with a constraint that seems automatic called NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height, that forces the height to 17 pixels:

> NSLayoutConstraint:0x61800008ea10 'NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height'
>   > V:[NotesTable(17)]   (Names: NotesTable:0x60000012e2e0 )

I'm not defining any constraint to 17 pixels, I've tried testing with some parameters that usually insert automatic constraints (autoresizesSubviews/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints/autoresizingMask) but I was only able to translate that 'special' constraint to another format and the grow doesn't get bigger.

Tried to search the web but I only get cases where that Encapsulated constraint makes sense and is useful.

Do you know where or how can I disable that constraint or change its value to the height I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table and outline views on OS X do not support automatically determining the row height from the dynamic height of the cell views. They either have an explicit static row height, a static row height determined by the design-time height of the cell views, or a dynamic row height determined by the delegate and its implementation of `-tableView:heightOfRow:` or `-outlineView:heightOfRowByItem:`.

For your case, you're going to have to implement the delegate method. Furthermore, the delegate method can't query the actual cell view because it may not exist and the outline view would need the row height before creating it. So, the delegate has to compute it some other way.

One way is to keep a standalone view hierarchy of a prototypical cell view. When the delegate is asked for the row height, it configures that view hierarchy as it would be for the actual cell view for that row/item, forces it to lay itself out, and then queries its height. Configuring the view hierarchy may be as simple as setting the `objectValue` of the top-level view (if it's an `NSTableCellView`, a control, or otherwise implements the setter). But if your delegate does other configuration, such as in its `-outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:` method, then you'll need to replicate that for this prototype view hierarchy.

Also, when any factor that would affect a row's height changes, you have to call the outline view's `-noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:` method to let it know that, so it will re-query your `...heightOfRow...` method.

Finally, bare table views are not especially amenable to being constrained to sibling views or their superview. They really want to live in scroll views and continue using springs-and-struts to position and size themselves. See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29559451/1312143) for a discussion of this. It is possible that this has been improved in recent versions of the OS. Anyway, you're going to have to observe the table view's frame-change notifications (and ask it to post such notifications) in order to know when it grows. And your ability to set constraints to relate it to any other views in the cell view hierarchy will be severely limited, because it will need `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` turned on.

Comment: Thank you very much Ken.